# Can someone explain linearisation on nonlinear systems to me?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I want to find all critical points of the following nonlinear system:
$$\def\b{\begin{pmatrix}}\def\e{\end{pmatrix}}$$
$$\b y_1' \\ y_2'\e = \b 5y_2  -15 \\y_2^2 - y_1 ^2\e$$

Then use linearisation to find the type and stability of the critical points.

---

So first of all, finding the critical points:
$$\b 5y_2  -15 \\y_2^2 - y_1 ^2\e = \b 0\\0 \e$$

Gives us $y_2=3$ and $y_2 = \pm y_1$

Giving us the critical points $(3,3)$ and $(-3,3)$.

Now I need to use linearisation to find the type and stability of the critical points, but I have no idea how to do this, and I have looked at two textbooks, but don't understand.

Can someone please explain this (likely simple) concept to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier notationally and conceptually to talk about a general system of the form  $y' = f(y)$. The idea is to approximate the system near a critical point by the closest linear one - that is, approximate $f$ near a critical point by the closest linear function. This is exactly what the first-order Taylor expansion does: if $f(y_0) = 0$, then $$f(y_0 + h) = \nabla f (y_0)\cdot h+\text{higher order terms.}$$

Thus we can approximate the nonlinear system near $y_0$ using the linear system $$h' = \nabla f(y_0) \cdot h.$$ In coordinates this is $$h_i ' = \sum_j \frac{\partial f_i }{\partial y_j} \Big|_{y_0}h_j.$$ So the linear approximation at a critical point is described by the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at that critical point. Once you have computed these matrices you can determine stability, etc as in the linear case - check the eigenvalues.

Comment: Just give me a little bit to understand this :)

Comment: So do each of the $y_1'$ and $y_2'$ equal $f_1(y)$ and $f_2(y)$?

Comment: @Calculus: yes.